# Not desired output

Tags: python

i am using only date not datetime but in the output i receive this "The days between the given dates is/are 4 days, 0:00:00" why there zeros are here.

```
from datetime import date
while True:
    while True:
                try:
                    print("\nInsert appropriate values for first date.")
                    year1 = int(input("\nEnter a year:"))
                    month1 = int(input("Enter a month:"))
                    day1 = int(input("Enter a day:"))
                except ValueError:
                    print("\nPlease enter only number")
                else:
                    break
    while True:
                try:
                    print("\nInsert appropriate values for second date.")
                    year2 = int(input("\nEnter  year:"))
                    month2 = int(input("Enter  month:"))
                    day2 = int(input("Enter  day:"))
                except ValueError:
                    print("\nPlease enter only number:")
                else:
                    break
    date1 =date(year1,month1,day1)
    date2 =date(year2,month2,day2)
    num_of_days=(date2 - date1)
    print("\nThe days between the given dates is/are",num_of_days)
    while True:
        Repeat=input("\nDo you want to calculate again\n\nYes or No:")
        Repeat=Repeat.lower()
        if Repeat not in ["yes","y","no","n"]:
            print("\nPlease select correct option")
        else:
            break


    if Repeat in ["yes","y"]:
        continue
    else:
        if Repeat in ["no","n"]:
            print("\n-----Thank you for using-----")
            input()
            break
```

The days between the giver dates is/are 13 days, 0:00:00
here(13 days, 0:00:00) here are 13 days the numbers 0:00:00 why its coming in output and what is solution.

Comment: I don't understand your sentence that starts with "The days between the giver dates is/are". Can you describe exactly what output you're getting, and exactly what output you want to have?

Comment: Why do you use `import` inside the `while` loop?

Comment: i want to count the days between input dates user gives

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python datetime subtract", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print `num_of_days.days`, just replace this line:

```
print("\nThe days between the given dates is/are", num_of_days.days)
```

Maybe you would also want to have `abs` if the dates are inversed and you would not want to have a negative number of days.

```
print("\nThe days between the given dates is/are", abs(num_of_days.days))
```

Answer (score 0):

The numbers `0:00:00` are the time portion of `datetime`. If you only want a date without a time, then just use `date` instead.

Comment: how to do it please elaborate

Comment: `datetime` and `date` are well documented in many places on line.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: @WaseemMunir There isn't much to elaborate. Just replace `datetime` with `date`.

Comment: thats the problem its giving error when i use date only

Comment: @WaseemMunir What error? Please edit your question to include this detail.

Comment: i have used date instead of datetime as you said but in output there are still 00:00:00 that problem is not solved